# php: how to validate textbox using jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a textbox, i would like to validate it using jquery-ajax once user  focusout from that textbox.

Validation include:

- Server side, value goes to the php page and i have to validate it
- if validation success,show alert("succes"); else if error alert("failed");

I have doubt how jquery ajax will show alert("failure");  Till now , i have only done for success.

I know only the below mention code,furthure what should i do to solve my problem? please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('input[id^="datepicker"]').on('focusout',function()
        { 
             $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_frmdate_validation.php?txtval="+$(this).val(),
                success: function(data){
                    alert('Successfully  ...');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>

--------------
--------------
<input class="plain" name="frmdate"   value="" size="25" id="datepicker" />
```

And my server side php code is:

```
$txtval =$_REQUEST['txtval'];
$fromTimestamp = strtotime( $txtval); 
//---------My Logic Code Goes Here -----------------------------
$sid=$_SESSION['id'];
$result12=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM budget where creater_id = '$sid'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result12);

if($num_rows>0)//check if empty or not
{
    while($test12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12)) {
        $from_date = strtotime($test12['from_date']);//getting all the FROM-Dates_column
        $to_date = strtotime($test12['to_date']);//getting all the TO-Dates_column

        if(isset($to_date) && isset($from_date)) {
            if((($fromTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($fromTimestamp <= $to_date)) || (($toTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($toTimestamp <= $to_date))) {
                $val = 'Y'; //return Y in meet this condition
            }
            else {
                $val = 'N'; // return N if meet this condition
            }
        }
        //---------------------Result of my logic code---------------------------------
        if($val == 'Y') //Returns TRUE
        {
            //VALIDATION FAILS - Returns Validation Error
            break;
        }
        else  if($val == 'N') {
            //VALIDATION TRUE - Returns Validation Error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just return the error message from the server and alert it in the success function

Comment: @Sabari please post it as an answer with few code as reference

Comment: Just offtopic. But escape this query `$result12=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM budget where creater_id = '$sid'");` at least with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @user2180861 Done. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
$txtval = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtval']);
$fromTimestamp = strtotime( $txtval); 
 //---------My Logic Code Goes Here -----------------------------
 $sid=$_SESSION['id'];
 $result12=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM budget where creater_id = '$sid'");
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result12);

 if($num_rows>0)//check if empty or not
 {
    while($test12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12)) {
    $from_date = strtotime($test12['from_date']);//getting all the FROM-Dates_column
    $to_date = strtotime($test12['to_date']);//getting all the TO-Dates_column

    if(isset($to_date) && isset($from_date)) {
         if((($fromTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($fromTimestamp <= $to_date)) || (($toTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($toTimestamp <= $to_date))) {
             $val = 'Y'; //return Y in meet this condition
         }
         else {
            $val = 'N'; // return N if meet this condition
         }
     }
     //---------------------Result of my logic code---------------------------------
     if($val == 'Y') //Returns TRUE
     {
        echo "failed";
        exit();
     }
     else  if($val == 'N') 
     {
        echo "success";
        exit();
     }
```

Now in your ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
       $('input[id^="datepicker"]').on('focusout',function()
       { 
         $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_frmdate_validation.php?txtval="+$(this).val(),
            success: function(data){
               if (data == 'success') {
                    alert("Successfully validated"); 
               } else {
                    alert("Failed");
                    return false;
               }
            }
        });

      });
   });
</script>
```

Rather than alerting, a better way will be to show the error message below the textbox by appending the message if it is failed.

Also do proper escaping before you do the checking using `mysql_real_escape_string`

**UPDATE** :

You need to call the ajax whenever the date changes in the input text field, so instead of `focusout` you can use `onSelect` from `datepicker`. So when a new date is selected an ajax call will be initiated.

So instead of calling the earlier ajax on `focusout` you can call on `onSelect` of datepicker

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect:function(date,instance){
           $.ajax({
              url: "ajax_frmdate_validation.php?txtval="+date,
              success: function(data){
                 if (data == 'success') {
                    alert("Successfully validated"); 
                 } else {
                    alert("Failed");
                    return false;
                 }
              }
           });
        }
    });
});
```

**NEW UPDATE**

Try with this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 
       $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" ,
          onSelect:function(date,instance){
                          $.ajax({
                            url: "ajax_frmdate_validation.php?txtval="+date,
                            success: function(data){
                            if (data == 'success') {
                                 alert("Successfully validated"); 
                            } else {
                                 alert("Failed");
                                  return false;
                            }
                     }
                 });
            }
     }); 
  }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: Above i shown you event `focusout` . And ,my textbox is  getting input from calender(jquery calender opens when user focus on the textbox)  . So according to my requirement which  event of jquery is suitable for  this?

Comment: @user2180861 I am not clear of what you mean. The event focusout you have used for the text box is correct for your requirement

Comment: I have a text-box , when i click on it. One j-query Calender is opening . so for this case i used `focusout` event. But `focusout` is not seems good . Can you suggest which event shall i use for this case??

Comment: @user2180861 Please check my update. Hope this is what you need

Comment: @user2180861 what is the response from the server. Use firebug to check for the ajax call

Comment: i am nt getting alert for simple implementation:  `$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect:function(date,instance){
         alert("hello");
        }
    });
});`

Comment: @user2180861 This event fires when you select a date in the date picker. Did you check in the console for any errors. Can you clear cache and try

Comment: Sorry, its same  problem. Its not calling my function

Comment: @user2180861 can you post your datepicker script

Comment: script:  `<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
                });
            });
        </script>`  ---------and textbox is------>`<input class="plain" name="frmdate"   value="" size="25" id="datepicker" readonly/>`

Comment: @user2180861 I am not sure. It is working for me. Is there any link I can check with

Comment: My textbox id is `datepicker` and you have mention `last_updated_date`  . Is this the wrong??

Comment: `Onfocusout` event, with my previous code, it was getting call, but with your jquery code its not calling. What could be the reason?

Comment: @user2180861 This is the correct way to call, but I am not sure Why it isn't working. If you can give me a link for checking the same, I can tell you what exactly the issue is

Comment: @user2180861 Sorry there was a mistake in the id I added, it should be datepicker I added as last_updated_date. I have corrected that. Can you please check now

Comment: Sorry, Still the same issue.. Not even giving any alert. But if i keep the old update done by you in my page , then i am getting alert but problem is that is in `onfocusout` event

Comment: @user2180861 Sorry I am not sure now What the error is. As I added before if you can send a link of that then I can check

Comment: Now problem Solved, After placing your new updated ajax script above the jquery calender script i.e (`$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
                });
            });`)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if($val == 'Y') //Returns TRUE
{
    //VALIDATION FAILS - Returns Validation Error
    break;
}
else  if($val == 'N') {
    //VALIDATION TRUE - Returns Validation Error
}
```

into

```
echo $val;
```

Then in your js simply grab response and do alert msg:

```
success: function(data){
    if (data == 'Y') {
        alert('Successfully  ...');
    } else {
        alert('Oh no...');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its easy use

```
 if($val == 'Y') //Returns TRUE
            {
                echo 'success';
            }
            else  if($val == 'N') {
                echo 'fail';
            }exit;
```

you will get this success/fail in the `data` param of your `success` call back.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code will be

```
if($val == 'Y') //Returns TRUE
            {
              echo "Success";   
             //VALIDATION FAILS - Returns Validation Error
                break;
            }
            else  if($val == 'N') {
              echo "Fail";   
                //VALIDATION TRUE - Returns Validation Error
            }
```

And In JS

```
$.ajax({
                           url: "ajax_frmdate_validation.php?txtval="+$(this).val(),
                           success: function(data){
                                      if(data == "Success")
                                        alert("success");
                                      if(data == "Fail")
                                        alert("Fail");

                           }
                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Until and unless you set the HTTP Response as an error code , ajax will not callback to fail: function.

An easy way to do is , send a JSON string back from the server side even if validation fails or is a success as shown in the format below.

If validation is a success

```
 {'status':'OK','message':'Validation success'}
```

If validation is a failure

```
{'status':'NOK','message':'Please enter your name'}
```

Now you can get this JSON string in the success callback and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax `type` and `data` option to send the data instead of passing it through url.

```
 $.ajax({
           url: "ajax_frmdate_validation.php",
           type:'GET',
           data:{"txtval":$(this).val()},
           success: function(data){
                 if(data=="success"){
                   alert('successful');
                 }else{
                    alert('error');
                 }
            }
         });
```

and you serverside code include this

```
  if($val == 'Y') //Returns TRUE
        {
           echo "success"
            break;
        }
        else  if($val == 'N') {
             echo "error";
             break;
        }
```